# Foreach through XML document with Powershell returning multiple nodes

Tags: xml, powershell

Trying to gather server and environment information from an XML document. But, when I use the foreach loop to iterate through the document, it returns both nodes in the tree, instead of one at a time.

```
[xml]$xmlDoc = [xml](Get-Content("C:\temp\compareVHD_info.xml"))

foreach($env in $xmlDoc.pvs.env)
{
    if($env -eq "prod")
    { do stuff}
}
```

XML:

```
<pvs>
  <env>
    <prod>
        <primaryServer>
            <name>name</name>
            <storePath>path</storePath>
        </primaryServer>
        <secondaryServer>
            <name>name</name>
            <storePath>path</storePath>
        </secondaryServer>
    </prod>
    <nonProd>
        <primaryServer>
            <name>name</name>
            <storePath>path</storePath>
            <storePath>path</storePath>
            <storePath>path</storePath>
            <storePath>path</storePath>
        </primaryServer>
        <secondaryServer>
            <name>name</name>
            <storePath>path</storePath>
            <storePath>path</storePath>
            <storePath>path</storePath>
            <storePath>path</storePath>
        </secondaryServer>
    </nonProd>
  </env>
</pvs>
```

I'm trying to gather the primary and secondary server names, the storepaths, and the store paths. Though, when I use the code above, it returns both "prod nonProd" in the $env variable

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Quick question. Do you need to loop through the xml file? Since you can load the xml file as an object you can use dot notation to access a node, or even use xpath using `.SelectSingleNode`

Comment: I'm trying to make it as dynamic as possible, for different client setups. So yeah, that would be best practice to loop through it.

Comment: When I use `.SelectSingleNode`, the $env variable has a bunch of information about the object, instead of the node string from the XML.

Comment: I guess I'm still not sure why you're not using XPath.  `$xmlDoc.SelectNodes('/pvs/env/prod')` should return all the `prod` nodes if you might have multiple.  XPath is very descriptive, although the syntax is not very user friendly.  If you want the raw XML, then reference either the `OuterXml` or `InnerXml` property of the nodes that function returns (depending on what makes sense).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code you posted can't possibly work. Your XML data has just a single `<env>` node, so your loop iterates over a single object with 2 properties (`prod` and `nonProd`), hence a check `$env -eq "prod"` will always evaluate to `$false`. What you actually want is to select the `<primaryServer>` and/or `<secondaryServer>` nodes and output the values of their child nodes.

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\input.xml'

$xml.SelectNodes('//prod/primaryServer') | ForEach-Object {
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
        Name = $_.name
        Path = $_.storePath -join ';'
    }
} | Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\output.csv' -NoType
```

If you want primary and secondary in the same file change the [XPath expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx) to something like `//prod/*[self::primaryServer or self::secondaryServer]` if there are other sibling nodes as well, or just `//prod/*` if those are the only child nodes of `<prod>`.